# How to upload a local file to a Carrierwave model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave to handle image uploads, but I'm not using a form, instead I use local files in the server.

How can I make this work?

```
@user = User.first
image_path = "/tmp/pic-s7b28.jpg"

@user.image = image_path
@user.save!
```

Comment: If you are using local files, how is that a file upload? I'm assuming that you want to do image manipulation through carrierwave?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
@user = User.first
image_path = "/tmp/pic-s7b28.jpg"

@user.image = File.open(image_path)
@user.save!
```

You can check examples in the [carrierwave readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Comment: will this solution close the file?