# Change user avatar to picture from assets/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

How to change user avatar to a picture that is in `app/assets/images` with *carrierwave*?

I have `avatar_uploader.rb`.

In my application there are several avatars to choose from, when I click on one of them, I send ajax request to controller with name of the picture.

What method do I need to use in controller to change user avatar to this picture?

I know the `user.remote_avatar_url` method for changing avatar using url of picture.

But I need a picture from `assets/images/`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [this solution from official docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file)?

```
restaurant = Restaurant.create!(name: "McDonald's")
restaurant.logo = Pathname.new(Rails.root.join("db/images/mcdonalds_logo.png")).open
restaurant.save!
```

There is also similar question asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16137722/4414956

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it seemed to me that this method greatly affects performance on production server. Let me know if this method does not affect performance. Thanks.